# WordPress post submit page

Tags: customization, pages

How to create a custom page in WordPress To submit a post? Where registered users can submit their post?

Comment: Hi Hafizur Babu, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 0):

Make all user author to contributor. After no user post directly you blog but submit article for review. Only Admin can publish.